# Building U-boot using ELDK

Tags: embedded-linux, u-boot, yocto

I installed a Embeded Linux Development Kit (ELDK v5.5.3 which is connected to Yocto project) withouth any problems on my system. It is installed in /opt/ARM/eldk-v553. At the end of installation I had to source this script in order to set the right enviromental variables:

```
export PATH=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin:/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi:$PATH
export PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi/usr/lib/pkgconfig
export CONFIG_SITE=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/site-config-armv5te-linux-gnueabi
export CC="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -march=armv5te -marm -mthumb-interwork --sysroot=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export CXX="arm-linux-gnueabi-g++  -march=armv5te -marm -mthumb-interwork --sysroot=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export CPP="arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -E  -march=armv5te -marm -mthumb-interwork --sysroot=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export AS="arm-linux-gnueabi-as "
export LD="arm-linux-gnueabi-ld  --sysroot=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export GDB=arm-linux-gnueabi-gdb
export STRIP=arm-linux-gnueabi-strip
export RANLIB=arm-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
export OBJCOPY=arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy
export OBJDUMP=arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump
export AR=arm-linux-gnueabi-ar
export NM=arm-linux-gnueabi-nm
export M4=m4
export TARGET_PREFIX=arm-linux-gnueabi-
export CONFIGURE_FLAGS="--target=arm-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux --with-libtool-sysroot=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export CFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types"
export CXXFLAGS=" -O2 -pipe -g -feliminate-unused-debug-types -fpermissive"
export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-O1 -Wl,--hash-style=gnu -Wl,--as-needed"
export CPPFLAGS=""
export OECORE_NATIVE_SYSROOT="/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux"
export OECORE_TARGET_SYSROOT="/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/armv5te-linux-gnueabi"
export OECORE_ACLOCAL_OPTS="-I /opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/share/aclocal"
export OECORE_DISTRO_VERSION="5.5.3"
export OECORE_SDK_VERSION="5.5.3"
export PYTHONHOME=/opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-
```

So after I finished I downloaded the U-boot sources from GIT, then applied a patch to the uboot in order to add configuration for EA3141 board and started the **crosscompilation** using make. I got an error:

```
make EA3131_config
Configuring for ea31xx board...
[ziga@Ziga-laptop u-boot]$ make
Generating include/autoconf.mk
Generating include/autoconf.mk.dep
for dir in tools examples/standalone examples/api ; do make -C $dir _depend ; done
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for '_depend'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/standalone'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for '_depend'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/standalone'
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/api'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for '_depend'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/api'
make -C tools all
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools'
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o env_embedded.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/common/env_embedded.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -o envcrc crc32.o env_embedded.o envcrc.o sha1.o
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o default_image.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/default_image.c
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o fit_image.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/fit_image.c
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o image.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/common/image.c
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o kwbimage.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/kwbimage.c
/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/kwbimage.c: In function ‘kwbimage_verify_header’:
/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/kwbimage.c:350:10: warning: variable ‘calc_exthdrcsum’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  uint8_t calc_exthdrcsum;
          ^
gcc -g -Wall -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O -c -o mkimage.o /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools/mkimage.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -O2 -fomit-frame-pointer -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include2 -idirafter /opt/ARM/u-boot/include -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/libfdt -I /opt/ARM/u-boot/tools -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -DUSE_HOSTCC -D__KERNEL_STRICT_NAMES -O  -o mkimage crc32.o default_image.o fit_image.o image.o kwbimage.o md5.o mkimage.o os_support.o sha1.o fdt.o fdt_ro.o fdt_rw.o fdt_strerror.o fdt_wip.o
strip mkimage
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/tools'
make -C examples/standalone all
make[1]: Entering directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/standalone'
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g  -Os   -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  -D__KERNEL__ -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -I/opt/ARM/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem /opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__ -marm  -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -march=armv5te -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-stack-protector   -o hello_world.o hello_world.c -c
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g  -Os   -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  -D__KERNEL__ -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -I/opt/ARM/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem /opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__ -marm  -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -march=armv5te -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-stack-protector   -o atmel_df_pow2.o atmel_df_pow2.c -c
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  -g  -Os   -fno-common -ffixed-r8 -msoft-float  -D__KERNEL__ -DTEXT_BASE=0x33600000 -I/opt/ARM/u-boot/include -fno-builtin -ffreestanding -nostdinc -isystem /opt/ARM/eldk-v553/eldk/armv5te/sysroots/i686-eldk-linux/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi/../../lib/arm-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.8.1/include -pipe  -DCONFIG_ARM -D__ARM__ -marm  -mabi=aapcs-linux -mno-thumb-interwork -march=armv5te -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-stack-protector   -o stubs.o stubs.c -c
arm-linux-gnueabi-ar crv libstubs.a stubs.o
r - stubs.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -g -Ttext 0xc100000 \
                -o hello_world -e hello_world hello_world.o libstubs.a \
                -L. -lgcc
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld: cannot find -lgcc
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'hello_world' failed
make[1]: *** [hello_world] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/opt/ARM/u-boot/examples/standalone'
Makefile:364: recipe for target 'examples/standalone' failed
make: *** [examples/standalone] Error 2
```

I assume the problem is in `-L` parameter which has a value of `.` and there is no gcc in the current folder. What should be the value of `-L`if anyone knows where are libs stored inside U-boot? In which makefile should I fix this L parameter? There are so many...

Comment: Just curious: why ELDK? Have you already tried [Buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/)? It provides both internally compiled toolchains  as also external like Linaro etc. As for U-Boot, you just need to point BR to the folder with your copy of U-Boot and then you can build it inside BR. See this [section](http://nightly.buildroot.org/manual.html#_advanced_usage).

Comment: Hmm this is interesting but it is like Openwrt - everything is in a form of objects. I don't like that because I can't understand anything... Even more important Is that **I found an example for building embeded linux Kernel using ELDK (is there an example of building with Buildroot?). It was simple - on LPCLinux there is a nice patch to add support for LPC3141. After patching I just build it using ELDK tools prefixed by arm-linux-*

Comment: Take a look at his [BSP](https://github.com/visionsystemsgmbh/onrisc_br_bsp). It uses mainline kernel (3.18.1) with some additional [patches](https://github.com/visionsystemsgmbh/onrisc_br_bsp/tree/master/board/vscom/kernel-patches/linux-3.18). So BR automatically downloads kernel sources, patches, compiles and puts kernel image to output/images folder. For development time, you can just tell BR to take source code from the folder you're working with kernel and it will rsync the source code and recompile it, i.e. only the changed files. Btw. BR is much user friendly than OpenWRT.

Comment: This topic is solved. I used a wrong patching procedure. Now everything works OK. I will reconsider of using the Buildroot. I didn't like Openwrt when I saw it at work...